# HTML5 / JS app not calling one of the .js files listed in index.html once .js files converted to UTF8

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, utf-8

I developed a game in RPG Maker MV. This is a javascript frontend that allowed me to develop block/scratch programming which is then exported by the RPG Maker MV backend into an ANSI/UTF8 mixture of html5 / .js files. In other words, I know nothing about programming in javascript that would help me debug the issue as described now that the above is out of the way.

Simplest Description:
How do I make this plugins.js file load once the .js files for my HTML5 app have been converted from ANSI to UTF8 BOM?

Issue:
Once my app is packaged using either WinJS or Cordova in Visual Studio 2017 (latest version of everything) for UWP destination, a certain .js file (plugins.js I believe) is not being utilized (called?) making the app not run correctly in its packaged form. I narrowed this down by packaging the app without converting .js files to UTF8 for UWP, and it runs fine. Once I convert the .js files to UTF8 and package it again, the core of the RPG Maker MV game backend works, but the additional plugins I added to it are not working.

Everyone I talk to about this issue shies away from it because they don't know what RPG Maker MV is or how it works. I don't understand why, because it is still just Javascript and literally anyone besides me spending 10 minutes would get farther debugging simply because you know what you are doing and I don't. I am seeking to understand but I am on the ground floor and have not made much headway since May when I started debugging this.

I posted this on the RPG Maker MV forums, visual studio community, contacted RPG Maker MV support (they don't support UWP), and tried to find someone on codementor.io to help me. I also asked around at work where we have literally hundreds of software developers but this issue doesn't appeal to a wide audience.

If you can help me you would have the thanks of myself and at least 3 reviewers of my published, broken game on the windows store. You would be an iconic hero for the ages, just like the one in my game. Well, actually it's an ironic hero.

Please, how do I make this plugins.js file load once the .js files for my HTML5 app have been converted from ANSI to UTF8 BOM?
    //
    // main.js
    //

```
PluginManager.setup($plugins);

window.onload = function() {
    SceneManager.run(Scene_Boot);
};
```

And index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">
        <link rel="icon" href="icon/icon.png" type="image/png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon/icon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/gamefont.css">
        <title>Likely Story RPG</title>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: black">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/pixi.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/pixi-tilemap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/pixi-picture.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/fpsmeter.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/lz-string.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/iphone-inline-video.browser.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/rpg_core.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/rpg_managers.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/rpg_objects.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/rpg_scenes.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/rpg_sprites.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/rpg_windows.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Update from comments below:
Ok I'm uploading a zip folder now (2.6 gb) with everything in it you or anyone might need. This replicated the issue perfectly and with far less complexity in the game's code. The way to tell it's not working: In debug in visual studio, the app has picture overlay on bottom left. Clicking with mouse should bring up a menu. In packaged app the picture displays but does not run a menu event. 1drv.ms/f/s!AhExycO0yDOZhsdmVSBkhw9t_HNn3w

Update: It looks like this was a pretty similar problem here, with no solution: [Grunt and UglifyJS in Windows app development - UTF8 problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352909/grunt-and-uglifyjs-in-windows-app-development-utf8-problems?rq=1)

Comment: We need code.... please edit your question and show relevant examples. And show the js you are using

Comment: Not even sure where to start, maybe that's why I never get anywhere? I will edit and show the only two places I can imagine there being a break in the code. Just need a minute.

Comment: So the plugins js you are talking about is second last to the bottom? Do you need main to be last or load before the plugins?

Comment: That's right. The contents are variables which define how some other .js files will function.

Comment: This same app when packaged for android works just fine it's worth noting.

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for logs or errors? Have you checked the network tab to see if the script is actually loaded or not? Have you tried adding `console.log` calls in that script to see if it gets loaded or not?

Comment: There are no errors in console except for this: pixi-picture.js.map read failed: Could not find file. I have been told by the people on RPG Maker MV forum that this error is not relevant but I would be glad to track it down if that is not necessarily true.
Another error happens according to microsoft support due to a "bug of Microsoft Edge engine, you can use temporary solution -
change null parameter in that function which you have the problem with on “function(){}”." So I did that and it resolved the error but does not resolve my package issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue.

Easy answer, there is a section of code in the file rpg_manager.js where "pluginmanager" is called as a function. This uses the flag script.async = false;

Changing the flag to script.async = true; was all it took to get the packaged runtime environment (which is IE for UWP apps) to work.

Longer-ish answer, I found this by a combination of having been in the right place and hearing about async, plus sleepless thinking about where the function might be going wrong. It was also due to some research on async found here: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/

I believe this explains why the build for android exhibited no issue, and debugging also had no issue as it is a different runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Move all of your script includes except for your plugins.js into the header which will make them load first, then you could do your plugins.js in the body which would make it load later.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">         <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">
        <link rel="icon" href="icon/icon.png" type="image/png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon/icon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/gamefont.css">
        <title>Likely Story RPG</title>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/pixi.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/pixi-tilemap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/pixi-picture.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/fpsmeter.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/lz-string.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/iphone-inline-video.browser.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/rpg_core.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/rpg_managers.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/rpg_objects.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/rpg_scenes.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/rpg_sprites.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/rpg_windows.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: black">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This will make plugins the last js to load, as it loads in the body, which loads after the header, which answers your question. Glad to be able to help.

Comment: It gave me error "exception unhandled" in debugging due to the main.js file expecting plugins.js to have already been called. I believe I may have misspoke but the real issue seems to lie with this plugins.js file just not being called somehow once I convert these .js files from ANSI to UTF8.
I'm very grateful you are looking into this, let me know any other .js files you'd like to see if it would help.

Comment: give me a link to main.js and i will take a look at it, or whatever initially loads everything.

Comment: also put a console.log in the top of every file. so you can atleast narrow down what file it is in. console.log('sprites'), etc..

Comment: Is there a way to add a debug alert similar to console.log which would run in the final packaged app? I believe the breakdown is occurring once the app has been packaged only since it functions as expected during Visual Studio debug sessions. It's almost as if the debug engine and the final package engine are two different engines and the packaged engine can't handle UTF8 BOM.

Comment: I am going to create a new project from scratch replicating the issue but without my creative content. I will then upload to a location that the whole thread here can DL the source visual studio project in its entirety. To do this will take me until a bit later tonight after I get home from work.

Comment: Okay, it might help you diagnose the problem, even adding content piece by piece? Maybe there is something specific to your content that is causing the issue

Comment: Ok I'm uploading a zip folder now (2.6 gb) with everything in it you or anyone might need. This replicated the issue perfectly and with far less complexity in the game's code. The way to tell it's not working: In debug in visual studio, the app has picture overlay on bottom left. Clicking with mouse should bring up a menu. In packaged app the picture displays but does not run a menu event. 1drv.ms/f/s!AhExycO0yDOZhsdmVSBkhw9t_HNn3w

Comment: your link didnt work the first time, now it does, I am downloading and will take a look at it

Comment: // Generated by RPG Maker.
// Do not edit this file directly. your plugins file states this at the top

Comment: So far i have not edited the file, I wouldn't know what to edit anyway since I'm not familiar with Javascript. I can't thank you enough for taking the time to glance at this project. My suspicion is that the original programmers did not account in their code for certain files being called once they were encoded in UTF8 BOM for use on UWP. I just don't know how one would accomplish this in javascript.

Comment: Couldn't you try to change the encoding at the top? I will look into this over the next week. I have it loaded up, but don't have time to delve into it right now

Answer (score 0):

You can try <[script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)> attributes for the correct loading scripts below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">
        <link rel="icon" href="icon/icon.png" type="image/png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon/icon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/gamefont.css">
        <title>Likely Story RPG</title>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: black">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/pixi.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/pixi-tilemap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/pixi-picture.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/fpsmeter.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/lz-string.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/iphone-inline-video.browser.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/rpg_core.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/rpg_managers.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/rpg_objects.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/rpg_scenes.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/rpg_sprites.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/rpg_windows.js"></script>
        <script defer type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script defer type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I will try this and package it shortly

Comment: This came with the same result I'm afraid, is there some javascript I can add that will help me narrow down where the breakage is occurring? Such as a UWP alert or something that will print to debug console of Visual Studio? If so where should I place the error checker?

Comment: Can you delete one file at a time from the .html file to understand which file is broken?

Comment: or use [debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) and put before the function where you expecting an issue

Comment: Good suggestion! Will attempt when I'm back home in a few hours, sorry for delay.

Comment: I just placed debugger and it works as advertised but I forgot to mention one detail. When I am debugging this app in visual studio, the app runs fine. It is calling all files and I have no issues. It is only once the app is packaged that the issue presents itself. Thus I would need something that could alert me for debugging once the app is packaged if possible.